# when using CodeIgniter redirect() causes a blank page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

when using CodeIgniter redirect() method with the 'refresh' parameter, mode_pagespeed causes a blank page - i.e. it doesn't follow the redirect.

Comment: There is no question here?

Comment: Following code [neither](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).